# Partitioning time into time blocks with PHP; issues with rationalizing current block

Tags: php

There is probably a much easier way to do this. Given my novice level of skill with PHP, I imagine there are some grievous errors with how I'm constructing this. I humbly accept any criticism, as I'm just starting out, and would be glad to learn better practices.

However, I'm trying to partition time into two-hour time blocks. The code is commented in accordance with each block, but I'd like it to say one is within the "4:00 PM to 6:00 PM" time block if it's currently 5:30 PM.

I'm not entirely certain how I would structure the if statement to properly select the time. I figure a more experienced set of eyes may be able to point out a solution. The currently included if statements do not work, but are included merely as an example.

This is obviously part of a greater script, but I'm pretty certain the issue lies within the following code. However, I can include the entire script if necessary.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // Set default time zone
$currenttime = date("G"); // Set the time in 24 hour format, no leading zeroes

if (0 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 8) {
    $thisblock="00:00:00"; // Overnights
}

if (8 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 10) {
    $thisblock="08:00:00"; // Eight to ten.
}

if (10 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 12) {
    $thisblock="10:00:00"; // Ten to noon.
}

if (12 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 14) {
    $thisblock="12:00:00"; // Noon to 2:00 PM.
}

if (14 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 16) {
    $thisblock="14:00:00"; // 2:00 PM to 4:00 PM
}

if (16 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 18) {
    $thisblock="16:00:00"; // 4:00 PM to 6:00 PM
}

if (18 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 20) {
    $thisblock="18:00:00"; // 6:00 PM to 8:00 PM
}

if (20 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 22) {
    $thisblock="20:00:00"; // 8:00 PM to 10:00 PM
}

if (22 >= $currenttime && $currenttime < 24) { 
    $currentblock="22:00:00"; // 10:00 PM to midnight
}

?>
```

Comment: You could use [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) objects as your "two-hour time blocks". You maybe could also use arithmetics to get the time for display. You always need to floor the hour to the next lower even number.

Comment: You should describe want you want to achieve to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, this will do what you want:

```
function get_time_block($currenttime)
{
    // if time is before 8, we'll just return the first, 8-hour block
    if ($currenttime < 8)
    {
        return '00:00:00';
    }

    // otherwise, return the first dividable-by-two number before this number as a block
    return sprintf("%02d:00:00", $currenttime - $currenttime%2);
}
```

To test it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++)
{
    print($i . ': ' . get_time_block($i) . '<br />');
}
```

This outputs:

```
0: 00:00:00
1: 00:00:00
2: 00:00:00
3: 00:00:00
4: 00:00:00
5: 00:00:00
6: 00:00:00
7: 00:00:00
8: 08:00:00
9: 08:00:00
10: 10:00:00
11: 10:00:00
12: 12:00:00
13: 12:00:00
14: 14:00:00
15: 14:00:00
16: 16:00:00
17: 16:00:00
18: 18:00:00
19: 18:00:00
20: 20:00:00
21: 20:00:00
22: 22:00:00
23: 22:00:00
```

.. which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any set of intervals with a simple formula that will take the time and "round" it to the right interval. In your case you would want something like this:

```
ceil($time/$interval)*$interval
```

So in your case, you can do something like:

```
$current_hour = date('G');
$check_hour = ceil($current_hour/2)*2;
switch ($check_hour) {
case 2:
...
case 4:
...
}
```

If you ever want to change the hour, it would be easy. A similar formula would work for any interval (hours, minutes, seconds, etc).